SSAO Looks Like Depth Buffer
I have problem with ssao, i'm using vulkan and follow Sascha Willems vulkan ssao example
here: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/ssao/ssao.cpp
my ssao result looks exactly like depth buffer with some artifacts.
#version 460
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl : enable


// in
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 aTangent;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 aBiTangent;
layout(location = 4) in vec2 aTexCoords;


// out
layout(location = 0) out vec3 vFragPos;
layout(location = 1) out vec3 vNormal;
layout(location = 2) out vec3 vTangent;
layout(location = 3) out vec3 vBiTangent;
layout(location = 4) out vec2 vTexCoords;
layout(location = 5) out vec3 vViewPos;

layout(location = 6) out vec3 vViewSpaceFragPos;
layout(location = 7) out vec3 vViewSpaceNormal;

// ubo
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform FrameUniformBufferData
{
    mat4 world;
    mat4 proj;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 invproj;
    mat4 normalmatrix;
    vec4 camera_parameters;
    vec4 campos;

    float lerpUserValue;
    float UserRoughness;
    float UserMetalness;
}ubo;

//push constants block
layout( push_constant ) uniform constants
{
    mat4 model;
} pc;


void main() 
{
    mat4 modelview = ubo.view * pc.model;

    vec4 pos = pc.model * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = ubo.proj * ubo.view * pos;

    mat3 normalmatrix = mat3(transpose(inverse(pc.model)));

    vNormal = normalmatrix * aNormal;
    vTangent = aTangent;
    vBiTangent = aBiTangent;
    vFragPos   = pos.xyz;
    vViewPos = ubo.campos.xyz;
    vTexCoords = aTexCoords;

    // Vertex position in view space
    vViewSpaceFragPos = vec3(ubo.view * pc.model * vec4(aPosition, 1.0));
    // Normal in view space
    mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(ubo.view * pc.model)));
    vViewSpaceNormal = normalMatrix * aNormal;
}

here is my gbuffer frag shader where I store ViewSpace Position and Normal in color attachments:
#version 460
#extension GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl : enable

// out
layout(location = 0) out vec4 OutAlbedo;
layout(location = 1) out float OutDepth;
layout(location = 2) out vec4 OutNormal;
layout(location = 3) out vec4 OutShading;
layout(location = 4) out vec4 OutPosition;

layout(location = 5) out vec4 OutViewSpacePosition;
layout(location = 6) out vec4 OutViewSpaceNormal;

// in
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vFragPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vTangent;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 vBiTangent;
layout(location = 4) in vec2 vTexCoords;
layout(location = 5) in vec3 vViewPos;

layout(location = 6) in vec3 vViewSpaceFragPos;
layout(location = 7) in vec3 vViewSpaceNormal;


// ubo
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform FrameUniformBufferData
{
    mat4 world;
    mat4 proj;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 invproj;
    mat4 normalmatrix;
    vec4 camera_parameters;
    vec4 campos;

    float lerpUserValue;
    float UserRoughness;
    float UserMetalness;
}ubo;

layout(set = 0, binding = 1) uniform sampler2D AlbedoTexture;
layout(set = 0, binding = 2) uniform sampler2D NormalTexture;
layout(set = 0, binding = 3) uniform sampler2D ShadingTexture;

vec3 getNormalFromMap()
{
    vec3 tangentNormal = texture(NormalTexture, vTexCoords).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0;

    vec3 Q1  = dFdx(vFragPos);
    vec3 Q2  = dFdy(vFragPos);
    vec2 st1 = dFdx(vTexCoords);
    vec2 st2 = dFdy(vTexCoords);

    vec3 N   = normalize(vNormal);
    vec3 T  = normalize(Q1*st2.t - Q2*st1.t);
    vec3 B  = -normalize(cross(N, T));
    mat3 TBN = mat3(T, B, N);

    return normalize(TBN * tangentNormal);
}

float linearDepth(float depth)
{
    float nearPlane = ubo.camera_parameters.x;
    float farPlane = ubo.camera_parameters.y;

    float z = depth * 2.0f - 1.0f; 
    return (2.0f * nearPlane * farPlane) / (farPlane + nearPlane - z * (farPlane - nearPlane));
}

void main()
{
    // calculate normal
    vec3 normal = getNormalFromMap();

    vec3 albedo = texture(AlbedoTexture, vTexCoords).rgb;
    float roughness = texture(ShadingTexture, vTexCoords).g;
    float metalness = texture(ShadingTexture, vTexCoords).b;
    
    OutAlbedo = vec4(albedo, 1.0);
    OutDepth = length(vFragPos);
    OutNormal = vec4(normal, 0.0);
    OutShading = vec4(roughness, metalness, 0.0, 0.0);
    OutPosition = vec4(vFragPos, 0.0);

    OutViewSpacePosition = vec4(vViewSpaceFragPos, linearDepth(gl_FragCoord.z));
    OutViewSpaceNormal = vec4(normalize(vViewSpaceNormal) * 0.5 + 0.5, 1.0);
}

also these are my color attachments:

ssao frag:
#version 460
#extension GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl : enable

// out
layout(location = 0) out vec4 OutColor;

// in
layout(location = 0) in vec2 vTexCoords;

layout (constant_id = 0) const int SSAO_KERNEL_SIZE = 64;
layout (constant_id = 1) const float SSAO_RADIUS = 0.5;

// ubo
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform SamplesUniformBuffer
{
     vec4 samples[SSAO_KERNEL_SIZE ];
}uboSSAOKernel;

layout(set = 0, binding = 1) uniform MatricesUniformBuffer
{
     mat4 projection;
}ubo;

// gbuffer
layout(set = 0, binding = 2) uniform sampler2D samplerPositionDepth;
layout(set = 0, binding = 3) uniform sampler2D samplerNormal;
layout(set = 0, binding = 4) uniform sampler2D ssaoNoise;

void main() 
{
    // Get G-Buffer values
    vec3 fragPos = texture(samplerPositionDepth, vTexCoords).rgb;
    vec3 normal = normalize(texture(samplerNormal, vTexCoords).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0);

    // Get a random vector using a noise lookup
    ivec2 texDim = textureSize(samplerPositionDepth, 0); 
    ivec2 noiseDim = textureSize(ssaoNoise, 0);
    const vec2 noiseUV = vec2(float(texDim.x)/float(noiseDim.x), float(texDim.y)/(noiseDim.y)) * vTexCoords;  
    vec3 randomVec = texture(ssaoNoise, noiseUV).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0;
    
    // Create TBN matrix
    vec3 tangent = normalize(randomVec - normal * dot(randomVec, normal));
    vec3 bitangent = cross(tangent, normal);
    mat3 TBN = mat3(tangent, bitangent, normal);

    // Calculate occlusion value
    float occlusion = 0.0f;
    // remove banding
    const float bias = 0.025f;
    for(int i = 0; i < SSAO_KERNEL_SIZE; i++)
    {       
        vec3 samplePos = TBN * uboSSAOKernel.samples[i].xyz; 
        samplePos = fragPos + samplePos * SSAO_RADIUS; 
        
        // project
        vec4 offset = vec4(samplePos, 1.0f);
        offset = ubo.projection * offset; 
        offset.xyz /= offset.w; 
        offset.xyz = offset.xyz * 0.5f + 0.5f; 
        
        float sampleDepth = -texture(samplerPositionDepth, offset.xy).w; 

        float rangeCheck = smoothstep(0.0f, 1.0f, SSAO_RADIUS / abs(fragPos.z - sampleDepth));
        occlusion += (sampleDepth >= samplePos.z + bias ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * rangeCheck;           
    }
    occlusion = 1.0 - (occlusion / float(SSAO_KERNEL_SIZE));
    
    OutColor = vec4(occlusion);
    OutColor.a = 1.0;
}

ssao result:

